# arrow functions: destructuring arguments and grabbing them as a whole at the same time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Can we do both destructuring: `({a, b}) => ( a + b )` and grab the arguments: `(...args) => ( f({...args}) )`, at the same time for arrow functions in ES6.

Looking for something like `(...args = {a, b}) => ( a + b + f({...args}) )`.

My curent solution is to do something like:

```
({a, b}) => {
  const {...args} = {a, b}
  return a + b + f({...args})
}
```

But it is redundant
or (thanks to nnnnnn & Dmitry)

```
(args) => {
  const {a, b} = args
  return a + b + f({...args})
}
```

which is less redundant and definitely better but still not entirely satisfactory.

Comment: If you're defining the function with destructured arguments `({a,b})`, doesn't that mean the function is getting called with only one argument, an object?

Comment: isn't that just `({a, b}) => a + b + f(a, b)` or `({a, b}) => a + b + f({a, b})`

Comment: @Slai. In my real problem I do not have just a and b. I have like 15 parameters with very long names. And depending on a condition I either use them and return something or I delegate to another function. These are not positional parameters but key based parameters. But you are technically correct. Yet of no help :(.

Comment: So when you call the other function `f()` do you want to pass it the original object that contained all the key-based parameters? What's `f()`'s signature?

Comment: @nnnnnn calling a function with an object that contains a bunch of key values is the same as calling it with the same key values as key parameters modulo syntax.

Comment: I thought that might be the case .. but it would help to add details like this in the question and the sample signature of `f`. Maybe using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) `({ a, b }) => a + b + ({...a} = {a, b}, f(...a))`.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's signature is abstract. It has a bunch of key based params that may or may not be there. but it is the same as the original function. This is actually the crucial point. I want `f`  to have the same signature as the original function even if I change it. And calling it with f(...args) where args are the arguments of the original function ensures that.

Comment: Assuming it has to be an arrow function (and thus no `arguments` object) my inclination would be to do `(args) => { const {a,b} = args; return a + b + f(args) }` - a bit like your current solution except you only need to list out the {a,b} part in one place.

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree with your last comment. I have just changed my solution.

Comment: The syntax of the pattern `...args = {a, b}` does not appear to be correct, where you are trying to destructure an iterable from an object

Comment: @guest271314 It is definitely not correct. I want a way to be able to destructure and grab the arguments as a whole in `args` at the same time. Is there a correct syntax for doing something like this?

Comment: @AdrianSilvescu You can use default parameter set to a plain object at source and object rest at target at destructuring assignment. Have you tried the code at Answer? Or is the code at Question hypothetical?

Comment: @guest271314 see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use default parameters and object rest at target of destructuring assignment for first parameter, where a single object is expected, and optionally define subsequent parameters by destructuring previously defined object parameter

```
const fn = ({...args} = {}, {a, b} = args) => console.log(a, b, args);
```

Comment: Note `= {}` at default parameter which prevents error if `a` or `b` is not defined

Comment: `fn({a:1, b:2})` prints `1 2 {}` in the console which means `args` is empty. I want `args` to include both a and b. Basically I want `args` to be the arguments to the original function call to `fn`.

Comment: @AdrianSilvescu Is a single object passed to the function?

Comment: @AdrianSilvescu `const fn = ({...args} = {}, {a, b} = args) => console.log(a, b, args)`

Comment: @AdrianSilvescu You can use previously defined arguments at subsequent arguments, the function parameter has its own scope. `a` and `b` are defined as distinct variables and are set as values within the object `args`, which contain `a`, `b` properties and the rest of properties set at the  object passed to the function.

Comment: @AdrianSilvescu What is the actual code and expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `let rComponent = 
( {...args} = {}, {
  m, m1,
  select, reset, nav,
  _debug, _sele, _page, location, r,
} = args) => {

/*  
( args ) => {
  const { 
    m, m1,
    select, reset, nav,
    _debug, _sele, _page, location, r,
  } = args
*/
  console.log(m, nav, args)
}`

Comment: your last suggestion `const fn = ({...args} = {}, {a, b} = args) => console.log(a, b, args)` seems to be working in the console. However my webpack babel polyfill seems to be ignoring the `{a, b} = args` part, but only partially (meaning it creates all the variables but they are left undefined).  Sorry for the late relpy.  If you change the answer appropriately I will accept it.

Comment: This is cool from the point of view of understanding the JavaScript language and execution, but I would cry if I ever saw this in a pull request. #notreadable #kiss #someonewillhavetomaintainthat

Comment: This is less of an interesting example of destructuring and more of a questionable use of a comma. All you're really doing is creating a totally unnecessary shallow copy of the `args` object. For example, `const fn = (args = {}, {a, b} = args) => console.log(a, b, args)` produces the same result as the given `const fn = ({...args} = {}, {a, b} = args) => console.log(a, b, args)`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that `f` also accepts named parameters, so why not just use:

```
(params) => {
  const { a, b } = params
  return a + b + f(params)
}
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but would not be accepting it for the reasons outlined in the question. Thank you though. nnnnnn also suggested the same solution in the comments.